# Spark generate a dataframe from two json columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with two columns. Each column contains json.

| cola | colb |
| --- | --- |
| {"name":"Adam", "age": 23} | {"country" : "USA"} |

I wish to convert it to:

| cola_name | cola_age | colb_country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | 23 | USA |

How do I do this?

---

The approach I have in mind is: In the original dataframe, If I can merge both the json to a single json object. I can then obtain the intended result

```
spark.read.json(df.select("merged_column").as[String])
```

But cant find an easy way of merging two json object to single json object in spark

**Update:** The contents of the json is not known pre-hand. Looking for a way to auto-detect schema

Comment: Use `from_json` function : `df.selectExpr("from_json(cola, 'struct<name:string, age:int>') as cola", "from_json(colb, 'country string') as country").selectExpr("cola.*", "country")`

Comment: Thanks. But what if the json contents is not known prehand. And need to autodetect it.

Comment: You always have simple json strings? No nested structures? If so, you can use some string concatenation to merge them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with pyspark syntax. I think this works:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema_cola = StructType([
  StructField('name', StringType(), True),
  StructField('age', IntegerType(), True)
])
schema_colb = StructType([
  StructField('country', StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame([('{"name":"Adam", "age": 23}', '{"country" : "USA"}')], ['cola', 'colb'])
display(df
        .withColumn('cola_struct', f.from_json(f.col('cola'), schema_cola))
        .withColumn('colb_struct', f.from_json(f.col('colb'), schema_colb))
        .select(f.col('cola_struct.*'), f.col('colb_struct.*'))
       )
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. But what if, we do not know the json contents prehand?

Comment: In that case I think this question can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088401/spark-from-json-with-dynamic-schema